# How to create fabric.Rect in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, fabricjs

How to create fabric.util.createClass (fabric.Rect) in typescript?
There is a code on js. I need a class on typescript.

**The JS**:

```
Grid = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    initialize: function (theParams) {
        this.type = "Grid";
        theParams = theParams || {};
        this.callSuper('initialize', theParams);
        this.top = theParams.top || 40 ;
        this.left = 0;
        this.offsetX = 0;
    }
});
```

[fabric.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/fabric)

**I'm writing on typescript:**

```
/// <reference types="fabric" />
declare const fabric: any;
export class Grid extends fabric.Rect {
    constructor(theParams?: any) {
        theParams = theParams || {};
        const options: fabric.IRectOptions = {
            type: 'Grid',
            top = theParams.top || 40 ;,
            left: 0
    };
    super(options);
    this.offsetX = 0;
}
```

**Error:**

*error TS2346: Call target does not contain any signatures.*

Comment: Try with an arrow function callback: `initialize: (theParams) => { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan
instead of constructor(theParams?: any) write initialize: (theParams) => { ... } ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought that `fabric.util.createClass` was your code.